# JQuery DataTables - ServerSide JSON - How to Populate columnFilter data when you have multiple pages

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am writing this up because I ran into this problem and while I found lots of people talking and asking about it, I found zero actual solutions.

When you change DT to serverside processing, then add per column dropdown filters, by default the dropdowns will only contain values that show on the first page.

Baseline Filtering: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html
Anyone searching on this will likely hit this post:
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/48780/server-side-column-filtering-with-drop-down-get-all-options

Which gives you a lead, but leaves out all sorts of details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to get the JSON columnFilters data and use that to populate the dropdown.

So you change:

```
column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>)
} );
```

To:

```
var json = buDueTable.ajax.json();
var filterData = json.columnFilters.Data_DT_Filters;
if (filterData != null) 
{
    var columnIdx = column.index();
    var thisFilterdata = filterData[columnIdx];
    if (thisFilterdata != null)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < thisFilterdata.length; j++) {
            select.append('<option value="' + thisFilterdata[j].filterItem + '">' + thisFilterdata[j].filterItem + '</option>')
        }
    }
}
```

For my example, I am using an IList class with IList of another class passed into the routine to format the JSON data.
In the first class, the property is named Data_DT_Filters, and in the second class the property is called filterData and the individual property within that is named filterItem

I hope this helps others trying to solve this problem.